# Transitivity of representation induction

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

Let $K\subset H\subset G$ be some triple of finite groups and $T: K\longrightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ - some representation f $K$. We are to prove the transitivity of induction: $Ind_K^G(V)\simeq Ind_H^G(Ind_K^H(V))$. I would like to do it somehow like that:
First, we identify $Ind_K^G(V)$ with the tensor product $\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[K]}V$ (it is $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module: $g:g'\otimes v\mapsto gg'\otimes v$). Thus, I need to show that $\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[K]}V$ is isomorphic (as $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module) to $\mathbb{C}[G]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]}(V\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[K]} \mathbb{C}[H])$. Is it possible to do it compactly, could you help?

Comment: The isomorphism $M \otimes_S (S \otimes_R N) \cong M \otimes_R N$ holds in general. Just construct an isomorphism using the universal properties. But the argument given in the answer below is the best one - using adjunctions the isomorphism becomes trivial.

Comment: You mean the isomorhism as modules over which ring?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg This shows that the underlying vector spaces of the representations are isomorphic, but is this enough to show that the modules are isomorphic?

Comment: @Sigurd The isomorphism of $R$-modules is natural, hence is compatible with any given actions.

Answer (score 3):

Induction is left adjoint to restriction. The restriction $G \rightarrow K$ is the composition $(H \rightarrow K) \circ (G \rightarrow H)$, so its left adjoint is the composition of the left adjoints.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!